# Simple 8 rooks game for beginner

Tags: java, mouseevent

Hi I am new to java and I thought I'd try produce a game where the user actually tries solving the 8 queens problem themselves. However, It increases in difficulty starting 8 rooks, up to 14 bishops then 8 queens.

I have created the chessboard successfully. I have a problem with my mouselistener... each square on the board is a button and when clicked my intention is that that square will change colour to indicate its been clicked, then all squares that cant be clicked on again will also change to indicate squares out of the game.

When the square is clicked it doesn't seem to perform any action.
Sorry, I know its trivial.
Thanks.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;


public class rooks extends JFrame implements MouseListener{

    private final int BOARD_SIZE = 8;
    private final int BOARD_SIZE_COLS = 8;
    private final int BOARD_SIZE_ROWS = 8;
    // private JTextField bottom = new JTextField("")                                                   ");
    // private JLabel bannerl = new JLabel("The game");
    // private JButton queens = new JButton(" Play Queens ");
    private JButton rooks = new JButton(" Play Rooks ");
    // private JButton bishops = new JButton(" Play Knights ");
    private JButton[][] cboard = new JButton[BOARD_SIZE][BOARD_SIZE];
    private JTextArea bottomtextarea = new JTextArea();




    // constructor creating the chessboard
    public rooks(){
        this.setSize(500, 500);
        this.setTitle("rooks");
        // this.setIconImage();

        // create JPanels and add JComponents
        JPanel main = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        this.setContentPane(main);

        JPanel north = new JPanel();
        north.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,3));
        main.add(north, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        // north.add(queens);
        north.add(rooks);
        // north.add(bishops);

        JPanel south = new JPanel();
        main.add(south, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        south.add(bottomtextarea);
        bottomtextarea.setEditable(false);
        bottomtextarea.setVisible(true);

        // create grid (actual chessboard) and initialise each button with no char
        JPanel chessBoard = new JPanel(new GridLayout(BOARD_SIZE, BOARD_SIZE));
        main.add(chessBoard, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        for (int i=0; i<BOARD_SIZE_ROWS; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<BOARD_SIZE_COLS; j++){
                cboard[i][j] = new JButton("");
                chessBoard.add(cboard[i][j]);

                // as it loops add colour to the board, if (i+j=even then white, otherwise black)
                 if ((i + j) % 2 == 0) {
                            cboard[i][j].setBackground(Color.black);
                        } 
                 else {
                            cboard[i][j].setBackground(Color.white);
                        }   
            }
        }

        cboard[7][7].addMouseListener(this);


        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){

    }
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

     }

     public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

     }

     public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

     }

     public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.print("it has been clicked");
     }

     void saySomething(String eventDescription, MouseEvent e) {

    }





}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding a MouseListener to the last button only, the JButton at cboard[7][7].

- Why use a MouseListener and not an ActionListener for JButtons? This makes no sense.
- Why not add an ActionListener to **all** JButtons inside of the for loop?

Comment: Thank you, I realized after i posted i was only putting it on one of the JButtons. I used ActionListener and put it inside the loop so it adds it to all buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working. I run it and when i click on the 7-7 square, (which is the one in the bottom right corner) i get the message: "it has been clicked".

Since you have added the mouse listener to only this square the code is behaving as expected.

But there are some things you should refactor:

- Why do you define BOARD_SIZE, BOARD_SIZE_COLS, BOARD_SIZE_ROWS? If you only use quadratic game boards you only need BOARD_SIZE and if not then you dont need BOARD_SIZE.
- Its convention to write the first letter of your classes in upper case. So it is Rooks instead of rooks
- You need to add your listener to every square of the board instead of to only one

This should be enough to start with.